# Python 3 replacement for fpformat.fix()

Tags: python, python-3.x

What would be an exact match for **fpformat.fix()** on Python 3?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/fpformat.html says that "*This module is unnecessary: everything here can be done using the % string interpolation operator*".  However, I seem to get a rounding error in **format_size()** that does not match **formatSize()**.  The following code relies on fpformat so it **must** be run on legacy Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import fpformat  # was removed in Python 3


def formatSize(amt):
    """Format a size as a string in MB"""
    return fpformat.fix(amt / 1024000., 1)


def format_size(amt):
    """Format a size as a string in MB"""
    # return "{:.1f}".format(amt / 1024000.)
    return "%.1f" % (amt / 1024000.)


for i in xrange(100000000):
    a = formatSize(i)
    b = format_size(i)
    assert a == b, (i, a, b)
# AssertionError: (153600, '0.2', '0.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `round(f,1)` , where f is your float value?

Comment: Unfortunately that gives the same result as format_size().